# Dropdown menu not positioning correctly with CSS in Laravel Blade template

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm working on a Laravel project and trying to position a dropdown menu on a banner in my header. I'm using a Blade template and have the following CSS under app.css:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;

}

.banner {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100vw;
}

.banner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; /* adjust as needed */
    left: 0; /* adjust as needed */
    z-index: 2;

}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Despite setting position: absolute; on the .dropdown and position: relative; on the header, the dropdown is not positioning correctly. Changing the top and left values in the .dropdown rule has no effect.

I've checked for conflicting CSS rules and didn't find any. The HTML structure is as follows under layout.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@yield('title', 'Default Title')</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="banner">
            <img src="{{ asset('images/banner.png') }}" alt="Banner Image">
        </div>

        <nav>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">Menu</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        @yield('content')
    </main>

    <footer>
        <!-- Footer content -->
    </footer>

    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The dropdown is a direct child of the header element. I'm not sure what else could be causing this issue. This is what is looks like currently:

[picture of banner with dropdown underneath. It should be on the banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQZnW.png)
I have my files saved and refreshed and all that stuff and I tried to change the .dropdown and it is not effecting the dropdown at all. there might be something else in my HTML or CSS that's causing the issue. But this goes beyond my help I can get by looking up things i have been at it for a while.

I will also include code from the home page under home.blade.php just in case but I don't think it has anything to do with the problem:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('title', 'Home')

@section('content')
    <h1>Welcome to My Website</h1>
    <p>This is the homepage.</p>

    <section>
        <h2>About Us</h2>
        <p>Some information about your website or company.</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>Our Services</h2>
        <p>A brief overview of the services you provide.</p>
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>Contact Us</h2>
        <p>Information on how to contact you or your company.</p>
    </section>
@endsection
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried adjusting the top and left properties in the .dropdown rule to position the dropdown menu at different places on the banner. I expected the dropdown menu to move based on the values I set for top and left, but it didn't move at all.

I've also checked for conflicting CSS rules and didn't find any that should affect the positioning of the dropdown.

I've confirmed that the dropdown is a direct child of the header element in my HTML, so it should be positioned relative to the header.

I've also tried removing display: inline-block; from the .dropdown rule, as I thought it might be interfering with the absolute positioning, but this didn't make a difference.

the only other thing I can think of is there is some sort of conflict or something that I don't know about.

Comment: Can't reproduce, with what info you have provided so far - https://jsfiddle.net/ansho35q/ Rather than showing us your template parts (which we lack the setup & data for, to produce the _exact_ result you are getting), you should provide a [mre] using the generated HTML code.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand where you want your "Menu" button. If you explain it to me, i'll try to make you something